# Generating a Workflow SID For use in task router

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, twilio

I'm attempting to create a Twilio webapp integration that will route calls to available customer service representatives in a browser.  To this end, I'm buidling a task router queue as documented here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/twiml-queue-calls

The documentation references a parameter: `workflowSid` to place a call in the appropriate queue.  I cannot figure out where this string comes from.  I figure there must be an interface in the Twilio app to create a new workflow and then there is a corresponding string for it but I can't seem to find where this is.

Comment: Ooh, tough crowd. Let me help you out. A Workflow (and it's corresponding `workflowSid`) is accessible from a Workspace. You can get the list of Workflows (and their `workflowSid`s) from the Workspace by its `workspaceSid`. See https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/workspace#fetch-a-workspace-resource. Utilizing the API you can get a list of all Workflows by accessing the Workspace's `links` `workflows` response. The URL you are looking for will look something like this; `https://taskrouter.twilio.com/v1/Workspaces/WSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Workflows`

Comment: @JohnSmith Thanks so much for the response.  I suppose part of this question is: where are these workflows created?  Do I need to break out Twilio studio to configure a workflow to a workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Workflow is similar to a Brain that will store the configurations to route your tasks correctly, it is created inside of a Taskrouter Workspace.

The Workflows can be created by API or via Twilio Console, it'll help you to route your tasks correctly, and workflow identifications initiate with "WW".

**To create a Workflow you need first have a Workspace created (Documentation: https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/workspace)

To create a Workflow by API, follow the documentation: https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/workflow.

To create a Workflow via Twilio Console follow the steps:

- Access the https://console.twilio.com
- Search for Taskrouter and access the "Taskrouter Workspaces" option
- If you're using a Flex Account probably will have a workspace already created, if not, you'll need to create a new one. Access it
- Access the Workflows, listed on left
- If you're using a Flex Account probably will have a workflow already created, if not, you'll need to create a new one.

With it, you can get the Workflow Identification, that started by "WW".

I hope that it can help you.

Comment: Wow, now that's an answer!  Many thanks sir.